# You have a box with 21 balls, 7 red, 7 white, 7 blue.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Compute the probability that if you were to draw 5 balls $without$ replacement, that you will have:

$a)$ 4 balls of 1 colour, 1 ball different colour

$b)$ at least one of each colour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should at least show some work, or let us help you figure it out. Here's a starting point: the probability of an event can be expressed as $\frac{\textrm{# of outcomes that result in event}}{\textrm{# of outcomes}}$. So the first probability is the number of ways to choose $5$ balls such that $4$ are of the same color, and the fifth is different, divided by the number of ways to choose $5$ balls. The second probability is the probability to choose $5$ balls such that you have one of each color, divided by the number of ways to choose $5$ balls total. You should know at least that the number of ways to choose $5$ balls is $21 \choose 5$.

For the first part, you should consider first which color you have $4$ balls of. How many colors can you choose so that you can have $4$ balls of that color? How many ways can you pick those $4$ balls? Once you've picked that color, how many colors can you pick to have $1$ of? In how many ways can you pick that $1$ ball?

For the second part, in how many ways can you distribute $5$ balls among $3$ colors so that you have at least one of each color?

Comment: a) Out of the 3 colors, I must choose 1. That is $\binom{3}{1}$.

Comment: Out of the 7 balls of that color, I must choose 4. That's $\binom{7}{4}$

Comment: There are 2 remaining colors, and I must pick one color. That's $\binom{2}{1}$

Comment: In that color, there are 7 balls, and I must choose 1. That's $\binom{7}{1}$

Comment: $$\frac{\binom{3}{1} \binom{7}{4} \binom{2}{1} \binom{7}{1}}{\binom{21}{5}}$$

Comment: @KracX Yes, that's right! Can you figure out part 2?

Comment: Okay so for 2 ... are there two cases I must consider?

Comment: Case 1: 3 of color one, 1 of color two, 1 of color 3

Comment: Case 2: 2 of color one, 2 of color 2, 1 of color 3

Comment: Is that right ?

Comment: @KracX Yes, that's right. Now you just need to find the probability of each of those two cases.

Answer (score 1):

4 balls of 1 color one ball of another.

$\frac {3{7\choose4}{14\choose1}}{{21\choose5}}$

rainbow:

Your chance of getting one ball of each color equals the chance of not getting 3 balls of one color, or 3 balls over any two colors.

1-P(5 balls all one color) - P(4 balls one color, 1 ball in a second color) - P(3 balls one color, 2 balls in a second color)

We don't need to consider P(2 balls one color, 3 balls in a second color) as we have already counted it.

P(5 balls all one color) = $\frac {{7\choose5}}{21\choose5}$

P(4 and 1) = $\frac {6{7\choose4}{7\choose1}}{21\choose5} = \frac {3{7\choose4}{1\choose1}}{21\choose5}$

P(3 and 2) = $\frac {6{7\choose3}{7\choose2}}{21\choose5}$

Put it all together.  The denominators are all the same.

P(rainbow) $=1 -\frac {3{7\choose5}+6{7\choose4}{7\choose1}+6{7\choose3}{7\choose2}}{{21\choose5}}$

Comment: I'm not sure how you did the second part, can you explain it more?

Comment: I added more detail.  Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done maths in ages... but how about this?

Total probabilities :

> 21 X 20 X 19 X 18 X 17 = 2,441,880

4 balls of 1 color, 1 ball different color :

> 21 X 6 X 5 X 4 X 14 = 35,280
>   35,280 / 2,441,880 = 1.44%

At least one of each color :

> 21 X 14 X 7 X 18 X 17 = 629,748
>   629,748 / 2,441,880 = 25.78%

Comment: I'm sorry to say, but that is incorrect from the start, as the total probabilities is $\binom{21}{5} = 20349$

Comment: @KracX Oh... I think my way is if the order we pull the balls matter.... Starting to get back to me now.